# Delete frames from a video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, edit-mode

I'm new to editing videos with blender. How can i delete selected frames from a video?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15376/2843

Comment: My best recommendation to trim videos by frames is Joyoshare [Video Cutter](https://www.joyoshare.com/video-cutter-win/). You can also refer to this guide, which tells you how to do it online: [Trim videos by frames](https://www.joyoshare.com/video-cutting/cut-videos-online.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you only need select the strip with the **Right Mouse Button** and press <kbd>K</kbd> to make cut where the cursor is positioned.

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry for asking, but how can i select the stream? I'm trying with [kbd]B[/kbd] then select the portion in the strip section, but it doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't delete the frames, stretching brings them back